# Is it possible to replace a value in a matrix with a list?

Tags: matlab, matrix, octave

For example, suppose I have a matrix

```
5 6 7 

1 2 3
```

and I want to change each element of the matrix so that they contain position information, and form a new matrix. Like

```
(5, 1, 1) (6, 1, 2) (7, 1, 3)

(1, 2, 1) (2, 2, 2) (3, 2, 3)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I did search for almost an hour, but I did not find any solutions... the majority of answers are for replacing elements with the same type, but here I want to replace numeric elements with lists. Could you provide me the links for relevant solutions if you found any? Thanks a lot!

Comment: I'm not sure I see the benefit of having the subscript of an element stored with the element itself. You'd have to have the subscript (or index) to access the subscript. What problem are you trying to solve with this?

Comment: Essentially, I will transform the original matrix using reshape a couple times, and reduce it to a smaller matrix, so only some the entries will be preserved. And I would like to know the position of these in the original matrix. That's why I want to store the position information along with the entry value.

Comment: From your description, it sounds like you should be able to generate an array of indices the same size/shape as your original matrix. Then perform exactly the same operations on the index array as your real array, and in the end you'll have the corresponding indices of the remaining elements. If you really need subscripts from there, you can use `ind2sub`.

Comment: If the posted answer solves your problem, consider marking it accepted. However you should be following beaker's suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

You could make them as cell arrays.
If the original matrix is called dat,

```
dat = [5 6 7; 1 2 3];
for i = 1:size(dat,1)
   for j = 1:size(dat,2)
      newdat{i,j} = [dat(i,j),i,j]
   end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

### Use additional dimension for list elements

If all elements have the same list length associated, what is always the case in your question, I would recommend the use of an additional dimension for your matrix to store the list elements.

```matlab
% your data
dat = [5 6 7; 1 2 3];
% Size of your data
s = size(dat)
% Create a target array with an added dimension with 3 elements
% 1st is your original data
% 2nd is first position index
% 3rd is second position index
dat1 = zeros([s,3]);
% Create an array with subscripts
[i1,i2] = ind2sub(s,1:numel(dat));
% fill in original data
dat1(:,:,1) = dat;
% Assign subscripts to your array
dat1(:,:,2) = reshape(i1,s);
dat1(:,:,3) = reshape(i2,s);
% Display result
dat1
```

This solution has an efficient runtime and memory behaviour, is fully vectorized (no for loops) and can be scaled to more dimensions or with a little effort to n-dimensional functionality.

[octave](/questions/tagged/octave)
[matlab](/questions/tagged/matlab)